# Компонент продвинутый грид на делфи

Tags: delphi, grid-layout

Добрый день! Наткнулся сегодня на интересный набор компонентов Virtual Controls. Установил себе его на делфи xe. В него входят компоненты TVirtualStringTree, TVirtualDrawTree и TVHeaderPopupMenu. Возможности этих компонентов поистине огромные, но как их использовать разобраться не удалось и как подлючить к примеру к базе данных компонент. Подскажите, может кто пользовался этими компонентами, знает как с ними работать? Прилагаю скрин демки-компилированной программы на основе этих компонентов.

[image]

И еще второй вопрос, для тех кто не работал с этими компонентами. Может вы знаете какие-то продвинутые гриды (бесплатные компоненты) многофункциональные? Буду благодарен за любые ответы... P.S. Использую delphi xe. Для старых делфи компоненты не советуйте.

Comment: Дельфисты отзовитесь! Что никто не использовал из вас какие-либо продвинутые гриды или деревья?

Answer (score 1):

Сразу оговорюсь, что данные компоненты не использовал, но принцип скорее всего похож.Ну и может ответ не совсем по теме вопроса.

```
но как их использовать разобраться не удалось и как подлючить к примеру к базе данных компонент
```

**Grid'ы**(как и различные **TreeView'ы**), на прямую к базе не подключаются, а используют для вывода компоненты с результирующим набором данных, для гридов обычно используется  **DataSourse**, для связи самого **Grid'а** с результирующим набором (**DataSet'ом**), а **TreeView** заполнить можно сразу из **DataSet'ов**

Comment: Об том что гриды связываются через Data Source, я знаю конечно. К сожалению я не нашел даже этой связки с компонентами. Похоже надо начинать читать мануал по компоненту, чтобы понять как связать его.

Answer (score 1):

А чем не устраивает вас [Ehlib](http://www.ehlib.com/en/screenshots)

[Бесплатная версия библиотеки EhLib - 3.6.](http://www.ehlib.com/ru/pokupka)

```
Лицензия на библиотеку версии ниже 3.6 не изменяется, т.е. граждане стран бывшего СССР, а также организации, зарегистрированные в них, имеют право использовать EhLib версии 1.X-3.X бесплатно:

Загрузить библиотеку EhLib 3.6, полнофункциональную версию с исходниками можно здесь

Пароль при распаковки архива - два раза имя второго месяца года большими буквами на русском языке.
```

Comment: Тоже хороший компонент. Спасибо за ссылку, возможно им и воспользуюсь для разработки продвинутого интерфейса баз данных.

Answer (score 1):

Пользуюсь ими довольно таки давно. Есть аналог TListView на их основе, зазывается TEasyListView.

С БД эти компоненты сами работать будут т.к. они всего-лишь средство отображения. TVirtualStringView предназначен для вывода текстовых данных. Его легко переключать в режим таблицы в настройках поставьте птичку toExtendedFocus.

В TVirtualDrawTree вы сами рисуете все данные буквально.

Если хотите именно их, то наследуете какой-либо компонент и прописывате ему работу с БД самостоятельно.